# If statement using interpolation always evaluates to true in Sass

Tags: if-statement, sass

I have an if/else statement running in an each function in scss.

I basically want it to make the text black if the background equals white

The @debug directive is telling me my statement is returning correctly, but all buttons end up with a black text color on hover? Am i missing something here?

```
//variables
$brand-primary:             #37a2c6 !default;
$brand-success:             #39c66a !default;
$brand-info:                #5bc0de !default;
$brand-warning:             #f7901e !default;
$brand-danger:              #e42829 !default;
$brand-haze:                #9e50da !default;

$color-white:               #ffffff;
$color-black:               #232323;


//map
$colors: (
  ("danger", $brand-danger, $brand-success), ("warning", $brand-warning, $brand-haze), ("success", $brand-success, $brand-primary), ("primary", $brand-primary, $brand-success), ("haze", $brand-haze, $brand-warning), ("pure", $color-white, $color-black)
);

//function
@each $color in $colors {   

  .btn--hollow {
    background: none !important;
    &.btn-#{nth($color,1)} {
      color: #{nth($color,2)} !important;
      &:hover {
        background: #{nth($color,2)} !important;
        @if #{nth($color,2)} == '#ffffff' {
          color: $color-black !important;
          @debug #{nth($color,2)} == '#ffffff' ;
        } @else {
          color: $color-white !important;
        }

      }
    }
  }

} //end each
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of interpolation here is casting the expression in your `@if` statement to a string.  When you write `@if 'somestring' { /* stuff */ }`, it will always evaluate to true.

```
$color: #ffffff;
$foo: #{$color} == '#ffffff';
@debug $foo; // DEBUG: #ffffff == "#ffffff"
@debug type-of($foo); // DEBUG: string

$color: #000000;
$foo: #{$color} == '#ffffff';
@debug $foo; // DEBUG: #000000 == "#ffffff"
@debug type-of($foo); // DEBUG: string
```

It is unknown if this behavior is intended, but this is one of many reasons why you should **not use interpolation unless you actually need to cast your variable to a string**.

```
$color: #ffffff;
$foo: $color == #ffffff;
@debug $foo; // DEBUG: true
@debug type-of($foo); // DEBUG: bool

$color: #000000;
$foo: $color == #ffffff;
@debug $foo; // DEBUG: false
@debug type-of($foo); // DEBUG: bool
```